# Python 3.4.3: Interpreting python input?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code started so far and I am lost now I have a headless program that will convert anything typed into it into **utf-16** and then decode **utf-16** also. I want it to support many other encryption types and eventually add a very simple gui to it.
My problem is this:

```
x = True
while x is True:
    print('''     You can type help, decode, info,  encode. or quit in the Command Line.''')
mInput = input('Command Line:')
if mInput == 'encode':
        #  print("     Write base utf or rot to be decrypted and then write the last number like base 32 or utf-16)
        iN = input("encode:")
        nC = iN.encode('utf-16')
        print(nC)
if mInput == 'decode':
        dC = input('decode:')
        dC = iN.decode('utf-16')
        print(dC)
if mInput == 'help':
            pass       
if mInput == 'info':
    print("This encodes anything you type in into your choice of encryption", '\n',
          "Or you can choose decode and will decode anything you type"
          "into english,")
if mInput == "quit":
    quit()
if mInput != 'decode' or 'encode' or 'help' or 'info':
    print(mInput, "is not a supported input please try again")
```

When i run this program it will encode and decode but it always saids my isnt suppported thing i wrote:

```
`if mInput != 'decode' or 'encode' or 'help' or 'info':
    print(mInput, "is not a supported input please try again")`
```

It always saids is not supported after i type in what i want encoded how can i fix this and write this program more pythonically lol :)

Comment: Your line `if mInput != 'decode' or 'encode' or 'help' or 'info'` does not do, what you want it to do! It will be interpreted like this: `if mInput != 'decode' or True or True or True:`. What you want is: `if mInput not in {"decode", "encode", "help", "info"}:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you do not use `elif`, it will run through if statement, even if it has succeeded in entering one, therefore it will always run through the last statement you have there.

What the last statement checks for, is to see if you input is not equal to, at least one of the strings your checking for. What you want to do is check to see if the input is not equal to ***all*** of the strings. So you would want:

```
x = True
while x is True:
    print('''     You can type help, decode, info,  encode. or quit in the Command Line.''')
    mInput = input('Command Line:')
    if mInput == 'encode':
        #  print("     Write base utf or rot to be decrypted and then write the last number like base 32 or utf-16)
        iN = input("encode:")
        nC = iN.encode('utf-16')
        print(nC)
    elif mInput == 'decode':
        dC = input('decode:')
        dC = dC.decode('utf-16')
        print(dC)
    elif mInput == 'help':
            pass       
    elif mInput == 'info':
        print("This encodes anything you type in into your choice of encryption", '\n',
        "Or you can choose decode and will decode anything you type"
        "into english,")
    elif mInput == "quit":
        quit()
    else:
        print(mInput, "is not a supported input please try again")
```

If you were to not use the if, elif, else statements, you would want to change your "or"'s in the last statement to "and".

Comment: Thank you very much but when I run this i keep receiving an error?

Comment: else mInput != 'decode' and 'encode' and 'help' and 'info':
              ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Silly mistake, see the above answer again